# bcrypt doesn't hash the password

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bcrypt

I have problem with hashing the password with bcrypt. I use version 5.0.0 and it works on other project, but now just ganerate the salt but not hashing. That is the code, I have used it before and it worked perfectly fine:

```
const { saltRounds } = require('../config');

module.exports = (mongoose, bcrypt) => {

    const { Schema, model: Model } = mongoose;
    const { String, Number } = Schema.Types;

    const userSchema = new Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        points: {
            type: Number
        },
    });

    userSchema.methods = {
        comparePasswords(password) {
            return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
        }
    };

    userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
        // Before we save the new user, we should crypt the password and save it like that
        let base = this
        if (!this.isModified('password')) {
            next();
            return;
        }

        bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds)
            .then(
                salt => {
                    console.log(salt, base.password)
                    bcrypt.hash(base.password, salt)
                        .then(hash => {
                            console.log(`Hash generated: ${hash}`)
                            base.password = hash
                            next()
                        });
                }
            ).catch(err => console.log(err));

    })

    return Model('User', userSchema)
}
```

and it doesn't catching any errors. i'll be grateful for any help. Thanks!